# How to see yago2s ontology like dbpedia owl?

Tags: owl, ontology, dbpedia, ttl, topbraid-composer

Hello I'm totally newbie in ontology.

I downloaded dbpedia ontology .owl file and open it using topbraid composer.

Topbraid composer shows dbpedia class( owl:Thing -> Activity, Agent, .. etc). Each class also has its own instances.

However, yago2s only provides many .ttl files( yagoSchema.ttl, yagoFact.ttl .. etc).
Cause I think these ttl files are similar to owl file, I also open it using topbraid composer.  I expected to see the structure like dbpedia owl file, but it wasn't similar to dbpedia owl file..
They provide schema ttl file, instances ttl file, ... files respectively, but i wanna see the whole thing at once.

Should I get yago2s owl file? or is there any ways to see yago ttl files like dbpedia owl??

Thanks in advance.

The error message when I tried to open yagoTypes.ttl file is

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:275)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$3.run(ProgressManager.java:960)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:995)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:970)
at org.topbraidcomposer.core.io.TBCIO$3.run(TBCIO.java:501)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.topbraid.core.model.Classes.getMetaClasses(Classes.java:548)
at org.topbraid.core.model.Classes.computeMetaClasses(Classes.java:45)
at org.topbraidcomposer.core.session.AbstractSessionWithCache.getCachedMetaClasses(AbstractSessionWithCache.java:67)
at org.topbraid.core.model.Classes.getMetaClasses(Classes.java:166)
at org.topbraidcomposer.editors.ResourceEditorLauncher.checkVisibility(ResourceEditorLauncher.java:270)
at org.topbraidcomposer.editors.ResourceEditorLauncher.access$4(ResourceEditorLauncher.java:269)
at org.topbraidcomposer.editors.ResourceEditorLauncher$5.run(ResourceEditorLauncher.java:577)
at org.topbraidcomposer.core.io.TBCIO$2.run(TBCIO.java:482)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

and this same error occurs when I concatenate yagoTypes.ttl and yagoFacts.ttl using cat command, and try to open this concatenated file..

Comment: Where did you get yago2s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where to get the data

If you got the data from [YAGO2s Downloads](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/), it says right at the beginning of the page:

> You can download the entire YAGO2s ontology in one piece. (Extracted
>   from 2012-12-01 version of Wikipedia.)
>   [Download YAGO2s ontology in
>   .ttl format!](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/download/yago/yago2s_ttl.7z) (2.2 Gb compressed, 18.5 Gb uncompressed)

That sounds like what you want.  If you just want to see the class hierarchy, though, then you might want the yagoTaxonomy files:

> **yagoTaxonomy** The entire YAGO taxonomy. These are all rdfs:subClassOf facts derived from Wikipedia and from WordNet.

### The format of the data

OWL is a ontology language with an abstract structure that can be *serialized* in a number of different ways including OWL/XML, the OWL Functional Syntax, the Manchester Syntax, and encoded as RDF.  Now, RDF is also an abstract format, and can be serialized in a number of ways, including N-Triples, N3, Turtle (ttl), and RDF/XML.  Most .owl files that you find are actually RDF/XML files that are serializations of the RDF encoding of an OWL ontology.  That's probably what your .owl file is. The .ttl files you're seeing are the Turtle serialization of the RDF encoding of an OWL ontology.  Standard RDF processing tools should be able to process it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I downloaded above hyperlinked file. However, after unzipping, that file is splitted into several files(yagoTaxonomy, yagoFact.. etc). I wanna see the only one file that contains both structure and instances.

Comment: And.. I used Topbraid composer(tool like protege) for seeing ttl files. I can see yagoTaxonomy.ttl but i can't see yagoFacts.ttl file..(The reasons that topbraid can't open file are bad IRI(warning message) and  javanullpointer exception(error).)

Comment: OK, the download link doesn't make it clear whether that's one compressed file or multiple files.  I guess it's a collection of files.  If the prefixes aren't conflicting, you could just concatenate them all together, and you'd still have a legal TTL file.  As for the errors in opening, you'll need to provide more details about those errors (e.g., edit your question to show the full error message, and if it provides line numbers, show the content in the appropriate TTL file at that line number).  The data might have bad values in it, or maybe TopBraid has a bug.  In either case a bug report…

Comment: …might be appropriate, but without more details, we can't really say to whom it should be sent.

Comment: Hm, the error message doesn't really help all that much, I guess.  It's doesn't point to any obvious problems.  I think that you may need to find some more specific TopBraid support (a mailing list or forum that they provide), and ask there. :(